# Android how to parse json into listtview inside a class that extends fragment

Tags: android, json, android-fragments

I am trying to do a fragment where there is a listview inside and I am trying to populate the listview using JSON. I only have one error and i dont know where to put the single error i have. The error says unreachable statement, when i put the getJSON() below the } it says  invalid method declaration

Here is my code with the listview inside a fragment. There error is pointing at the getJSON(); below the rootview. Thanks

```
public class News extends Fragment {
    private ListView lv;
    private String JSON_STRING;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(news, container, false);
        lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView3);
        return rootView;
        getJSON();
    }




    private void showResult(){
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSON_STRING);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.TAG_JSON_ARRAY1);

            for(int i = 0; i<result.length(); i++){
                JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(i);
                String NID = jo.getString(Config.TAG_NID);
                String title = jo.getString(Config.TAG_title);
                String content = jo.getString(Config.TAG_content);
                String n_date = jo.getString(Config.TAG_n_date);
                HashMap<String,String> match = new HashMap<>();
                match.put(Config.TAG_NID, NID);
                match.put(Config.TAG_title,title);
                match.put(Config.TAG_content,content);
                match.put(Config.TAG_n_date,n_date);
                list.add(match);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                getActivity(), list, R.layout.newsadapterlayout,
                new String[]{Config.TAG_title,Config.TAG_content, Config.TAG_n_date, Config.TAG_NID},
                new int[]{ R.id.title, R.id.content, R.id.n_date});
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    private void getJSON(){
        class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {


            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                JSON_STRING = s;
                showResult();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
                String s = rh.sendGetRequest(Config.URL_NEWS);
                return s;
            }
        }
        GetJSON gj = new GetJSON();
        gj.execute();
    }



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `getJSON()` call is after your `return` statement, so it is not possible for it to ever be executed. That is what the "unreachable statement" error means.

You could move your `getJSON()` call to the line before your `return` statement and it should solve that problem. Without running it it's hard to know if there will then be **other** problems, but at least that one should be solved.

Answer (score 1):

Protip: put errors you don't understand into your favorite search engine. In this case a search for `java unreachable statement` will yield plenty of results explaining that your problem is that you have a statement after a `return`:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(news, container, false);
    lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView3);
    return rootView; // <- Returning from the function here
    getJSON(); // <- How is this supposed to get executed if you already returned?
}
```

Call `getJSON` *before* returning from the method.